# Unable to fetch rows from MySQL database using php, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, html, mysql

as I said I am trying to fetch rows from MySQL database and I am simply not getting rows from it to show in table, what am I doing wrong?

Basically, I have index.php file (which contains HTML) + PHP in it.

Here's my try and what I tried to do:

```
<?php
$connect = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "dbname");
if ($connect != null) {
  echo "connected";
}
else {
  echo "failed to connect ";
}


$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM vozila";
$qry = $connect->query($sqlQuery);
?>
            <table border="1">
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>UNIT/ID#:</th>
                                    <th>PROIZVOĐAĆ</th>
                                    <th>REGISTARSKE OZNAKE</th>
                                    <th>VIN#</th>
                                    <th>GODINA</th>
                                    <th>SLIKA</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                            <?
                            while ($row = $qry->fetch_assoc()) {
                            ?>
                            <td>
                            <?
                              $row["ID"];
                            ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <?
                              $row["make"];
                            ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                            <?
                              $row["regoz"];
                            ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                            <?
                              $row["godina"];
                            ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                            <?
                              $row["slika"];
                            ?>
                            </td>
                            <?
                            }
                            ?>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am getting "connected" printed out on my web-page, it's just that it doesn't show rows filled with data inside of table.

What my goal is:
-Get data from MySQL database and fill table with that data.

Screenshot:
[image: Example]

Comment: You just query, you dont actually use the `mysqli_fetch` command to grab the results. you gotta loop it with a `while`. You execute the query, but you are not actually doing anything with it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am doing it? `while($row = $qry->fetch_assoc()){` as you can see here?

Comment: whoops didnt see it in the code itself. can you `print_r($row)` after this, and see your return

Comment: I'd like this question to be closed, as I found my way around with help from this source: https://laratutorials.com/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-in-php-and-display-in-html-table/

Comment: Probably want something like `printf($row["ID"]);` for each data element rather than the bare variable reference.